# PHP Read from a CSV-file

Tags: php, csv

I have a simple CSV-file which looks like this:

```
Value:
AAA
Value:
BBB
Value:
AAA
```

I want to count the number of times a certain value shows up (e.g. AAA).
To start, I want to get the lines which read "Value:" and just echo the following line "line[$i+1] which would be the corresponding value.
Here's the code:

```
<?php

$file_handle = fopen("rowa.csv", "r");

$i = 0;

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

$line[$i] = $line_of_text[0];


if($line[$i] == "Value:"){

echo $line[$i+1]."<br />";

}

$i++;
}

fclose($file_handle);

?>
```

The outcome should look like this:

```
AAA
BBB
AAA
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work..It just gives me "<*br /">s

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) example provides, you can use this modified code:

```
<?php
    $count = 0;

    if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            $num = count($data);

            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++)
            {
                if (!strcmp($data[$c], 'Value:')) continue;
                if (!strcmp($data[$c], 'AAA')) $count++;

                echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            }
        }

        fclose($handle);
    }
?>
```

**UPDATE**

Try this new code, we use the value as array key and increment the count for that "key".

```
<?php
    $counts = array();

    if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            $num = count($data);

            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++)
            {
                if (strcmp($data[$c], 'Value:'))
                {
                    if (!isset($counts[$data[$c]]))
                    {
                        $counts[$data[$c]] = 0;
                    }

                    $counts[$data[$c]]++;
                }

                else
                {
                    // Do something
                }
            }
        }

        fclose($handle);
    }

    var_dump($counts);
?>
```

You can print the array like this:

```
foreach ($counts as $key => $count)
{
    printf('%s: %d<br/>' . "\n", $key, $count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't hardcode "AAA"..I don't know those values

Comment: Is just an example, your question is not very clear. What you want to do? count every instance of a _word_ or count every _word_ repetition except `Value:`? Also provide a valid real CSV file example.

Comment: My final output would be: AAA: 2, BBB: 1

Comment: Thank you! This is the right direction..but it shows only "1" after each value

Comment: I have fixed the bug in the condition, try now ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are printing on command line or a file, you need to use \n instead of `<br/>`. That only works if your output is HTML. Also every time you want to move two lines. the logic should look like this:

```
if($line[$i] == "Value:"){
    echo $line[$i+1]."\n"; // add a new line
}
$i+=2; // you want to move two lines
```

Comment: sorry, doesn't change anything.

Comment: I just updated my answer.. did you try that? Are you outputting in a html?

Comment: Thanks, but why should I jump by two?

Comment: That will reduce the total run to half as you already know Value: shows up in every other line.

Comment: I see, but I only gave you an example. There are other lines between. I can only be definitely sure, that the actual value follows the "Value:"-line.

Comment: I also gave an example based on your example. You never mentioned what's your output type.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a normal everyday CSV file, but here's an example that should work.

```
$fh     = fopen('rowa.csv', 'r');
$OUT    = array();
$C      = 0;
while( ! feof($fh) ) {
    // read 1 line, trim new line characters.
    $line = trim(fgets($fh, 1024));
    // skip empty lines
    if ( empty($line) ) continue;
    // if it's a value line we increase the counter & skip to next line
    if( $line === 'Value:' ) {
        $C++;
        continue;
    }
    // append contents to array using the counter as an index
    $OUT[$C] = $line;
}
fclose($fh);
var_dump($OUT);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a CSV file. The `file()` command will load the lines of a file into an array. The `for` loop prints every second line.

```
$lines = file("thefile.txt");
for ($i = 1; $i < count($lines); $i = $i + 2) {
    echo $lines[$i] . "<br/>" . PHP_EOL;
}
```